# How to handle event multiple times with different selector ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below markups

```
<section id="section1" class="home-section home-38 homepagesection-section1">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 thronex night_out_lists">
    <ul class="ajax-terms">
       <li id="app-105"><a data-slide-index="0" href="javascript:void(0);" class="">Find Friends</a></li>
       <li id="app-107"><a data-slide-index="1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</a></li> 

    </ul>
  </div>
 </section>


<section id="section2" class="home-section home-38 homepagesection-section2">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 thronex night_out_lists">
    <ul class="ajax-terms">
       <li id="app-108"><a data-slide-index="0" href="javascript:void(0);" class="">Find Friends</a></li>
       <li id="app-109"><a data-slide-index="1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</a></li> 

    </ul>
  </div>
 </section>

<section id="section3" class="home-section home-38 homepagesection-section3">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 thronex night_out_lists">
    <ul class="ajax-terms">
       <li id="app-110"><a data-slide-index="0" href="javascript:void(0);" class="">Find Friends</a></li>
       <li id="app-111"><a data-slide-index="1" href="javascript:void(0);" class="">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</a></li> 

    </ul>
  </div>
 </section>
```

**Requirements** - I want to run below event for all `ul` with their respective `id`s

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        speed: 1000,
        infiniteLoop:true,
        pager:true,
        controls:false,
        pagerCustom: 'ul Ids here'

    });
```

**Problem** - So far I tried like this but it effects only first and second `ul` with it's `li`s and third one is replaced with first `ul`'s id

```
 $('.thronex:nth-child(1)').each(function() {

        $(this).children('li').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
            class: 'ajax-terms',
            id: 'bx-pager1'
        }));

        $(this).children('div').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
            class: 'bxslider'
        }));

        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            auto: true,
            speed: 1000,
            infiniteLoop: true,
            pager: true,
            controls: false,
            pagerCustom: '#bx-pager1'

        });
});

 $('.thronex:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
        class: 'ajax-terms',
        id: 'bx-pager2'
    }));

    $(this).children('div').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
        class: 'bxslider'
    }));
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        speed: 1000,
        infiniteLoop:true,
        pager:true,
        controls:false,
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager2'

    });
});

 $('.thronex:nth-child(3)').each(function() {

    $(this).children('li').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
        class: 'ajax-terms',
        id:'bx-pager3'
    }));
    $(this).children('div').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
        class: 'bxslider'
    }));

    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        speed: 1000,
        infiniteLoop:true,
         pager:true,
        controls:false,
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager3'

    });
});
```

**Note**: In above code ids will be added to `ul`s at the time of page load

I don't know what I am doing wrong.Any right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling `$('.bxslider').bxSlider(..)` over and over again on the same elements (remember `$('.bxslider')` will return all the elements with `.bxslider` class) which is something you don't want to do.

what I understand from your code is that you want to wrap all your `li` in a `ul` and then all you `div` in a `ul` too.

You need to take out

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        speed: 1000,
        infiniteLoop: true,
        pager: true,
        controls: false,
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager1'

    });
```

from `.each(function())` and put it after the `.each` is finished

also use different class names for all the `bxslider` in each loop. i.e.

```
$('.thronex:nth-child(1)').each(function() {

    $(this).children('li').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
        class: 'ajax-terms',
        id: 'bx-pager1'
    }));

    $(this).children('div').wrapAll($('<ul/>', {
        class: 'bxslider slider1'
    })); 
  });

   $('.slider1').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        auto: true,
        speed: 1000,
        infiniteLoop: true,
        pager: true,
        controls: false,
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager1'

    });
```

and so on.

BTW, you need to refactor your code as a lot of it is being duplicated

Comment: class '.bxslider' should not be changed.Ref http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1

Comment: no worries. just add another (dummy) class and use it. see updated answer